# How to get current route name in Component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I want to get current route name in controller.
I tried: this.route, this.curentRoute, this._routerRoot but Nothing Works.

```
computed: {
    currentRoute:{
      get(){
        console.log(this.__routerRoot);
      }
    },
}
```

How to get router name?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably what you are looking for is:

`console.log(this.$route.name);`

or simply

`console.log(this.$route);`

to get all the informations about the current route